# How to append data to an object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Heres is how I add data to my object:

```
    let trade = [
       new RecordStock(elem, recordtime, stockquantity, tradetype, stocksymbol),
   ]
```

The problem is when I run this:

```
 console.log(trade[0].price);
```

It seems that overwrites my object from the beginning.

I add my class code. How i can print the first data from the object

```
    class RecordStock {

  constructor(price, timestamp, stockquantity, tradetype, stocksymbol) {
    this.price = price;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.stockquantity = stockquantity;
    this.tradetype = tradetype;
    this.stocksymbol = stocksymbol;
  }
  static recordTrade(){
    console.log(price[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite? The object inside the array will stay as is from the time you initialised the array.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi when I execute a function and console.log(trade[0]) it always print a different object. Example: Input: price => 100. When I save it in an object it  works perfect but when I want save more prices in the object like 101  I want when I print price[0] keeps the number 100 and NO the 101.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand but are you trying to add objects to the trade array as you execute a function?

Comment: Yes but I want to push the information creating a new object but not overwrite the data in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inside the function I declare de var every time. I put let trade out of the function

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to push objects into the `trade` array. You can achieve this by simply appending to the array.

You can push objects with something like this

Assuming you have a function that adds the `RecordStock` object. Here is how it could be.

```
let trade = [];    

trade.push(new RecordStock(elem, recordtime, stockquantity, tradetype, stocksymbol));

trade.push(new RecordStock(elem, recordtime, stockquantity, tradetype, stocksymbol));

trade.push(new RecordStock(elem, recordtime, stockquantity, tradetype, stocksymbol));
```

Now you can access the latest RecordStock you pushed using this `trade[trade.length - 1]`. trade[0] will always contain the object which you pushed first. This is the usual array functionality.

Comment: the name of the class is called RecordStock

Comment: Did you initialise trade using `let trade = []`?

Comment: no...now works the problem is that iam printing trade[0] that always is the data i put but trade.object[0] i dont know how i can print

Comment: I have added my class

Comment: I updated the answer a little. But I am still un clear as to what you want to achieve. Please post a working snippet if this did not solve your issue.

Comment: I console.log the lenght of the trade and every time I call the function it still the same lenght (3) and not +3 (when i call the function).

Comment: Can undestarnd better now?